# How to disable multi touch on UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I am asking this question because on my custom `UIPageViewController`, I can swipe left or right from last to first page using exactly one gesture.

In other words, while I swipe with first finger, I am able to continue swiping with my second finger only when I put second finger on the screen BEFORE I leave the first one. It leads me to some troubles related to updating the view while swiping.

The question is how to disable described above case with multi touch. **How to prevent from behaviour like above?**

Comment: any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

Set UIView.exclusiveTouch Property.
This will accept the BOOL value YES or NO.
I think it might help you.